# Is TLS needed on loopback for local security?

Tags: network, permissions, sniffing, unix, user-management

So the scenario is that we have a server shared with a number of users, with me being the server administrator and able to determine permission assignments.

The server is running a service on loopback interface which is only protected by a plaintext password. However this service needs to be limited access to a subset of users. So my questions are:

- Do I need to put TLS on this loopback service to prevent sniffing of the plaintext password by unauthorized users? Or,
- since only root (or processes with certain capabilities) can sniff interfaces, does this mean even without TLS, the password is already safe from all non-privileged users?

Comment: What if the service crashes and another user opens a server on that port?

Comment: @user253751: This would be impossible. By default the ports 1 - 1023 are privileged and only root can listen to them. No other user will be able to listen to the port 443. Even if other port is used for TLS, you can redefine privileged ports.

Comment: @mentallurg who says the service runs on port 443?

Comment: How do users reach this server, so that calls come from localhost? SSH?

Comment: @user253751: Who is saying it is not? And even if, then - as I said above - one can still make it privileged and no user except root will be able to listen to it.

Comment: You seem to safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

> Would TLS meaningfully improve the security of this system?

*YES*, assuming you implement it in a good way. It certainly won't reduce the security, and can prevent some attacks. If the client is a thick app rather than a browser, you can quite substantially improve the security. However...

> If I add TLS, will that make this system secure?

*NO*, even with TLS, loopback sockets are generally not a secure method of IPC. Besides, there's no good reason to use them in a system like this. Almost every other method of IPC is much more secure, and usually also faster, more reliable, and more feature-rich.

> Do I need to put TLS on this loopback service to prevent sniffing of the plaintext password by unauthorized users?

Probably not (unless you have e.g. a network tap interface enabled with permissive access control). However, that's not the only risk.

> Or, since only root (or processes with certain capabilities) can sniff interfaces, does this mean even without TLS, the password is already safe from all non-privileged users?

No, that restriction isn't sufficient by itself to protect the password, or the service in general. See more detail in the next section.

Also, depending on exactly what you mean by "plaintext password", this system might broken regardless of the communication channel. For example, it is entirely possible to carry out a timing attack for linear-time brute forcing of a password if you have local code execution on the server, even with very limited privileges (e.g. within a browser JS sandbox), so your app would need to be secure against that. Other, more complex side-channel attacks might also be possible. Finally, simple brute-forcing is a significant risk.

---

The main thing that TLS would add to this scenario is the ability for the server to prove its identity to the client (by passing a certificate that only the legitimate service has the public key to), before the user submits a password. Without TLS, you generally can't do that. In the specific context of HTTP[S], this doesn't even necessarily help, because HTTPS has no way to say *which* certificate you expect to find, and no public CA will issue a certificate for a loopback address, so it may be difficult for the browser user to distinguish between trusted and untrusted certificates.

Envision a scenario: the server crashes for some reason (possibly because a malicious user specifically threw a lot of garbage data at it to try and cause this). Before it restarts, the same loopback port is bound by another process - one started by a low-privilege user - and presents the same interface (including, if it's a web server, the same web pages). This fraudulent server waits for other users - including you, the administrator - to come and log in. As you do so, it silently harvests passwords, passing them to the malicious user. The user then kills the fraudulent server and waits for the real one to come back online, at which point they log in as you (or anybody else whose credentials they captured).

HTTP[S] is also particularly high risk due to all the cross-site attacks (particularly CSRF, and possibly also XSS and clickjacking) that you need to protect against. CORS, if enabled, is also very dangerous with local servers (unless you give them a "real" domain name *and* a trusted TLS certificate to match).

Loopback sockets are approximately the only form of IPC that don't offer any means of identifying either the client or the server, restricting what users can run either the client or the server (unless the server is privileged and listening on a reserved port, and the attacker lacks such privileges), or securing the communication against eavesdroppers or misdirection. TLS solves some of these weaknesses, but not all of them (unless you go full mutual TLS where both sides know exactly what certificates are expected and will reject any other outcome). Local / UNIX Domain sockets (on *nix or recent versions of Windows) or named pipes (especially on Windows; the *nix version of them works but has fewer features and is in general less ideal) are a much better option.

Comment: *Before it restarts, the same loopback port is bound by another process* - this can only work for services bound to ports 1024 and higher.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Correct, assuming that the attacker doesn't have a process privileged to start a listener on a reserved port. I do mention that a little further down, below the scenario itself. However, loopback IPC very frequently uses high ports. (Indeed, sometimes careless devs make it use a port that the OS may automatically assign when connecting a TCP socket, in which case the service might randomly fail to work even without malicious users.)

Comment: I see, so this theoretical attack really shows how loopback is a bad mechanism since any local user can bind to high ports without much effort of authentication/authorization. Even if I could switch to Unix sockets that would be much safer, right?

Comment: Unix sockets are just like normal files in terms of permissions, so it must be safe.

Comment: Assuming the socket is created in a location where the privileged users can't create their own files (no write access on the directory) but can write to the socket (necessary for the client to work, obviously), that should be fine, yes. You could also make the socket be somewhere completely inaccessible to most users, but have a setuid client which assumes the relevant permissions (and also reports its real UID to the server, even), but frankly that's got its own risks (an attacker can't throw garbage at the socket, but can try to break the client for EoP).